# Can these two equations both be squares in $\Bbb N^+$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any examples where
$$a^2+2ab+2b^2=p^2,2a^2+2ab+b^2=q^2\qquad{a,b,p,q\in\Bbb N^+}\tag1$$
If not, can $(1)$ be disproven?

Testing by brute force brings up nothing for small integers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the equations:
$$(a+b)^2+b^2=p^2$$
$$(a+b)^2+a^2=q^2$$
Two Pythagorean triples. If a + b is odd, one of a and b must be odd and the triangle with two odd legs cannot be Pythagorean. If a and b are even and part of a solution they can be divided by two to yield another solution. Thus, we consider the case when a and b are odd.

Write $a=m^2-n^2$ and $a+b=2mn$, $m>n\geq1$, so the (a, a + b) triangle is Pythagorean:
$$b=-m^2+2mn+n^2$$
This must now be a perfect square for the (b, a + b) triangle to be Pythagorean:
$$(a + b)^2+b^2$$
$$=m^4-4m^3n+6m^2n^2+4mn^3+n^4$$
However, this polynomial is irreducible over the integers and thus has no square root with the conditions on m and n imposed above. The original equations have no solution.

(We can safely assume that both triples are primitive, since any factor k introduced into the first triple will necessarily propagate into the second triple and can be divided out afterwards. Thanks to Joffan for pointing this out.)

Comment: Thank you. This will also disprove another post of mine: Simplified rational distance problem, which didn't get much attention, likely because of the way I posed the question.

Comment: Do you know that you can mark one answer on your questions as the accepted answer (green tick)?

Comment: @ Parcly Taxel - Yes, I do.

Comment: Was just worrying. I only saw one of your questions where you did apply the green tick...

Comment: This is good analysis, so +1, but the conversion $a=m^2-n^2$ etc neglect the possibility that the two cases are not primitive pythagorean triples.

Comment: Hm... in triple 1, put a factor k into the expressions for a and b. Propagate this to the final polynomial; you'll see that there's a k^2 term, and any square root would be k * (irreducible polynomial root), which can't happen. So if the first triple is not primitive the second must not be too. Indeed we can divide by k throughout and leave ourselves with primitive triples.

Comment: Might not be the same multiplier in both?

Comment: OK, strike that; even if there is another multiplier, there will still be a common factor to divide out. So I agree that we can consider the primitive case  to determine. I suggest you update your answer to include the relevant points from this discussion ;-) Good job.

Comment: I've made the clarifying edit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this polynomial is irreducible over the integers and thus has no square root with the conditions..."? All that we need is for the expression to evaluate to a perfect square. EG $m^2 + 5n^2 $ is irreducible, but for $m = 2, n = 1$, we get $ m^2 + 5n^2 = 9 = 3^2$.